# How to make surface drawing faster than the debug pointer location (Samsung Notes App does it!)

Tags: android, samsung

I have a Galaxy Note with S Pen and enabled "Pointer location" in Developer options, so that I see how Android follows the stylus tip.

I wrote a simple app with Vulkan. I created a SurfaceView, passed the surface to C++, and there I initialized Vulkan presenting onto the surface. The pipeline just draws lines along vertices that represent the coordinates from OnTouch events.
That is, I have built an app for drawing lines.

Setting present mode for VkSwapchain to VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR **removes any delay between the debug pointer location and the line drawn by the app**. Nonetheless, there is a huge lag between the stylus tip and the debug pointer when drawing.

The thing is that when I open the Samsung Note app, the official app for note taking, I see that lines drawn have no lag between line and the stylus tip at all. **Moreover, the line drawn in the app is faster than the debug pointer location!** Drawing any curves in the app does not appear like the app is trying to predict the movement based on velocity or something like that. I think that the app somehow circumvent the default Android rendering process to manage to draw faster.

Does anyone have an idea how the Samsung Note app manages to draw frames following the stylus tip faster than Android draws the debug pointer location?

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with drawing? It seems to me that the issue is the response time of the pointer location data, not how the location data gets drawn. Maybe the Samsung Note app is getting lower-level information that is retrievable faster than the "debug pointer location".

Comment: **Samsung** Note app on a **Samsung** Galaxy Note -- I bet there is some special Samsung stylus input API that the app is using, which has lower latency than the official Android APIs.

Comment: Use [S Pen Remote SDK](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-spen-remote/s-pen-remote-sdk.html).

Comment: @Martin Zeitler, the `S Pen Remote SDK` does not help because it gives only event listeners for the button and the gyroscope of S Pen. I tried it and the gyroscope gives me acceleration only when I move the pen, not when I move the tip. That is, I got no events even when the Samsung Note app read the input from the tip correctly.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, you are right, it does not necessary related to rendering. My assumption was based on my experience with the present mode VK_PRESENT_MODE_MAILBOX_KHR on my desktop: if I do not limit the amount of renders per second, then I generate so many frames that a lag between the cursor and a drawn curve appeared because the latest frames were shown with a delay. I think that it can be something like that in relation to how SurfaceFlinger works.

Though, of course, I am also currently searching for a way to measure is there a delay in OnTouch events.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, for the record, I tried to measure time elapsed between successive OnTouch events and it is constant 60 events per second. Therefore, if a delay there, then it's a delay in coordinates rather then call number.

Comment: @Thomas, I bet on that too. And if it so, it is a shame Samsung does not provide an API for their method because it really blocks developers from creation of a competitive note tacking app like those on Apple. My Apple Pencil has just zero lag between the pen tip even in 3rd party apps.